# Leetcode Ex. 204: Count Primes

Tags: python, primes

I am learning Python using LeetCode problems and came across the Count Primes problem.
I have created a solution, however, the program returned 'Time Limit Exceeded' when submitted. 
I am not sure why this happened.
Why did this happen and how could I improve my solution to make it more time efficient?

Brief:
Count the number of prime numbers less than a non-negative number, n.

Example:

Input: 10
Output: 4
Explanation: There are 4 prime numbers less than 10, they are 2, 3, 5, 7.

My Solution:

```
class Solution:

    def isPrime(self,n: int) -> int:
      isPrime = False
      count = 0
      for i in range (1,n+1): # Iterates through integers (acting as divisors) from 1 to n
        if n % i == 0: # aka if n is divisible by i
          count = count + 1
      if count == 2: # if n only divisible by itself and 1
        isPrime = True
      return isPrime

    def countPrimes(self,n):
      totalPrimes = 0
      for i in range(1,n): # runs from 1 to n-1
       answer = self.isPrime(i)
       if answer == True:
        totalPrimes = totalPrimes + 1
      return totalPrimes
```

Comment: Your prime checking algorithm is trivial and inefficient. The test can not complete in time with it. BTW there must be thousands of questions about prime checking on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Horribly inefficient.  For example, why are you checking even numbers in the given range?  The only even prime is 2, so count it explicitly if it is in range and then only check to odd numbers.  You can find other improvements with some internet research, including on this site.

Comment: a faster way of generating primes in bulk is "prime sieve" - google a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways to count primes in a certain range (but very inefficient and time consuming for large numbers). You seem to have the right idea, we will first need a function that *correctly* determines if n is prime or not (Some primality tests that are fast like Fermat and Miller-Rabin give false positives). Trial division is the easiest to implement (it is only practical for small numbers however). For each input n we will check to see if there is a prime p < sqrt(n) that divides n. If so, n is composite, otherwise, n is prime. Here is my solution:

```
import math
def is_prime(n):
    trial_divide=[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31]
    if (n < 32):
        if n in trial_divide:
            return(1)
        else:
            return(0)
    if (n < 1001):
        for p in trial_divide:
            if (n%p==0):
                return(0)
        return(1)
    if (n > 1000):
        f = round(math.sqrt(n)+1)
        trial_divide=count_primes(f)
        for p in trial_divide:
            if (n%p==0):
                return(0)
        return(1)
```

We haven't defined count_primes yet so inputs above 1000 will cause an error. Here is the prime-counting function (actually, it returns the primes less than or equal to n):

```
def count_primes(n):
    primes=[]
    for i in range(n+1):
        if is_prime(i):
            primes.append(i)
    return(primes)
```

Putting two and two together, we can call the count_primes function with something like 2000:

```
print(count_primes(2000))
```

which should return the primes less than 2000:

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541, 547, 557, 563, 569, 571, 577, 587, 593, 599, 601, 607, 613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 643, 647, 653, 659, 661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709, 719, 727, 733, 739, 743, 751, 757, 761, 769, 773, 787, 797, 809, 811, 821, 823, 827, 829, 839, 853, 857, 859, 863, 877, 881, 883, 887, 907, 911, 919, 929, 937, 941, 947, 953, 967, 971,977, 983, 991, 997, 1009, 1013, 1019, 1021, 1031, 1033, 1039, 1049, 1051, 1061, 1063, 1069, 1087, 1091, 1093, 1097, 1103, 1109, 1117, 1123, 1129, 1151, 1153, 1163, 1171, 1181, 1187, 1193, 1201, 1213, 1217, 1223, 1229, 1231, 1237, 1249, 1259, 1277, 1279, 1283, 1289, 1291, 1297, 1301, 1303, 1307, 1319, 1321, 1327, 1361, 1367, 1373, 1381, 1399, 1409, 1423, 1427, 1429, 1433, 1439, 1447, 1451, 1453, 1459, 1471, 1481, 1483, 1487, 1489, 1493, 1499, 1511, 1523, 1531, 1543, 1549, 1553, 1559, 1567, 1571, 1579, 1583, 1597, 1601, 1607, 1609, 1613, 1619, 1621, 1627, 1637, 1657, 1663, 1667, 1669, 1693, 1697, 1699, 1709, 1721, 1723, 1733, 1741, 1747, 1753, 1759, 1777, 1783, 1787, 1789, 1801, 1811, 1823, 1831, 1847, 1861, 1867, 1871, 1873, 1877, 1879, 1889, 1901, 1907, 1913, 1931, 1933, 1949, 1951, 1973, 1979, 1987, 1993, 1997, 1999]
```

To check how many there are, call

```
print(len(count_primes(2000)))
```

which gives 303 primes in this range.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think this challenge helped me understand my solutions don't only need to work, but need to be efficient as well.